# Mistake in Rasmussen & Williams 2006 or my mistake?

Tags: machine-learning, trace, hessian-matrix

I wonder if I make any stupid mistake understanding this, or can there actually a mistake in the bible of Gaussian Processes: [Rasmussen & Williams 2006: Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/)?

See page 125 below. Since $W$ is defined as **negative** second partial derivation, shouldn't it change the sign in (5.23) and result in $+{1 \over 2}[(K^{-1}+W)^{-1}]_{ii}{\partial^3 \over \partial f^3_i}\mathrm{log} \ p(y|\hat{f})$ instead?

[image]

Comment: After having a look at their impressive errata list on your link I wouldn't be surprised it is a typo in the reference.

Comment: thanks @A.Γ. for comment :-) When I saw it I though the opposite, that it's unlikely that so many mistakes were corrected but not this one :-) But perhaps you are right! Anyway, I'd be grateful for any comments on the math itself - either confirmations (or the opposite) towards what I propose. Do you think my correction is correct?

Comment: I seems to me that you are right. What I concern a bit is that they have the same minus later on in the pseudo-code. May it be that the typo is earlier somewhere and this typo makes the think correct again? Well, it is not the easiest text to read for me.

Comment: @A.Γ. thanks: I don't think so; it looks like all is correct except this step and the final term should be without minus; and it looks to me like the Algorithm just copied the mistake. It goes even further!! Looks like the paper of [Groot et al 2014](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fast-Laplace-Approximation-for-Gaussian-Processes-a-Groot-Peters/8681281fadefcdef2ae5aea28910d54368c461f7) copied the mistake as well!

Comment: I am not an expert in statistics, but one thing I would do is to try one-dimensional example. The minus sign mistake in the derivative should be quite easy to catch if you have any feeling for what's going on when you interpret the process.